# Laravel 5 route иногда вылетает ошибка 404 not found

Tags: laravel, route

Добрый день. Есть путь прописанный в route, который осуществляет поиск по названию:

```
json/categories-search/{name}
```

Почти во всех случаях, какую категорию бы мы не пытались искать на UTF-8 кодировке, он находит.

Но... при поиске "охран***" происходит ошибка.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

На данный момент у меня нет никаких даже догадок, что это может быть...

PS: вставка в самой функции поиска

```
public function getCategoriesSearch($name)
{
    dd($name);
    ...
}
```

ничего не дало, все та же ошибка при этом слове...

Comment: Скорее всего символы звездочки не проходят regexp но тут стоит вопрос зачем ты их прешь в адресную строку, возможно поиск сделать все же лучше через переменную в get?

Comment: Возможно не совсем понятно описал, но "звездочки" - это любые символы. Т.е. при поиске слова начинающегося с "охра" происходит такого рода ошибка.

Comment: распечатай лист  `php artisan route:list`, и посмотри, как он видит там твое правило, скорее всего лара не может распарсить твою звезду, поэтому повторюсь не делай поиск в строке а сделай поиск через get

Comment: Отлично он его там видит. Если бы не видел, то в остальных случаях не работал бы...
`| GET|HEAD | json/categories-search/{name}                                                              |      | App\Http\Controllers\Json\JsonCategoriesController@getCategoriesSearch                       | web        |`
Еще раз повторю НЕ В ЗВЕЗДАХ ДЕЛО, а в слове начинающимся на "охра". Т.е. при вводе слова "охра" уже происходит эта ошибка! В остальных случаях все отлично!
PS: ajax запрос и так строится через type: 'GET'